# How to change "Searched Location" for Google Services Plugin

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I changed flavors path to "src/flavors/"
So I have "src/flavors/flavor1"

But Google Services Plugin is searching in "src/flavor1"

```
all {
  flavor -> sourceSets[flavor.name].setRoot("src/flavors/${flavor.name}") 
}
```

Comment: Do you have this file `google-services.json` in your app directory? show me your dependency in build.gradle

Comment: I have, problem that Google Services Plugin searching in src/<flavor1> directory, but I changed this path to src/flavors/<flavor1>